# Element or class LIKE selector for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sql-like

For whatever reason I have these classes called `.main_sub1`, `.main_sub2` etc. Never mind why I can't have `.main .sub`.

Is there a way with jQuery, sort of in the way it is possible to do with attributes, to get the classes containing `main`?

Comment: You said it yourself; class is an attribute.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Using `$("[class^=main]")` will select all elements whose classname **starts with** 'main'. Take a look at [jQuery docs about selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), there are a lot of other variations you can use, for example:

- `[class*=main]` will select elements whose classname **contains** 'main'
- `[class~=main]` will select elements whose classname **has the word** 'main' (delimited with spaces)
- `[class$=main]` will select elements whose classname **ends in** 'main'

Comment: will this work when class has been added to the element by 'addClass' method and not as an attribute?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can use an attribute selector to match certain values for the `class` attribute.

```
$('[class^=main]') // class begins with "main"
$('[class*=main]') // class contains "main" anywhere within it
```

Answer (score 3):

In this instance, I would just treat the class attribute in the same way as you do a standard attribute.

```
$("[class*=main]")
```