# value of foreach jquery input name

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach

this is about foreach function in JavaScript/jQuery.

I would like some help with wildcard of an input name

example: when any of the inputs' names that starts with 'field_{something}' are clicked.

Comment: There is no question here. This is pseudocode at best, not jQuery. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Matt, If i knew the code of jQ i wouldn't post here ... i posted the code the way i know it which is pseudocode...anyways @dotsamuelswan answered my question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very well formatted, but it kind of sounds like you're looking for a wildcard selector.

```
$("[name^=field_]").click(function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

More at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697542/is-there-a-wildcard-class-selector).

Comment: exactly wildcard selector .. any field that has the name of 'field_{something}'

Comment: Above is the syntax for a wildcard selector.  I would consider using either class or id as opposed to name.

Comment: Actually I can't use class, as html output of the inputs is made through a php class that is iOnCube encoded. which is why I can't add class to it. it only adds #IDs

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name^=field_]").each(function(){
 var currentInput = this;
 //...do something ...  
 });
```