# Select elements where class contains the string 'award' (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of li items that I want to select based on the class name and if it contains the string 'award'

I have the following html..

```
<li class="award"></li>
<li></li>
<li class="award-open"></li>
```

How do I select the two li items that have the class with the string 'award' in it?

Comment: Pressed that Post Question a little bit early ;)

Comment: sorry yeh i am writing the question - but you are right :)

Comment: The rest has been censored.

Comment: ... We'll wait ...patiently hohohoh

Comment: Sorry about that I was using the keyboard and accidently pressed ENTER on the submit question ;) Doh? :)

Comment: Thanks for being patient too :)

Comment: Guys, stop jumping on this question with answers already. This is a "exact" duplicate, and should've been searched for.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697542/is-there-a-wildcard-class-selector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```
$("[class*='award']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.elementClass[class^="xyz"]').each(function() {
// do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if(getElementByTagName("li")[i].className=="award";)
```

This will do from java script otherwise in jquery already answered by @Adil  and in place of i you have to loop it in for because tag name will return more than one li select as much you want.