# jQuery loop in function while calling selector possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a few dynamically builded forms and belonging ID's. The ID's look like `id='send_1'... id="send_2"...`

Gernerally it will be posted only one form but I don't know how many forms will be created so that I need one general jQuery-function that does the work. At the moment the code below works just for one ID. So I thought it must be possible to loop within a selector with something like `while` or `foreach` if something like that exists?

```
$(document).on("submit", "#paypal", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( /\,/.test( $('#send_1').val() ) ) {
        $('#send_1').val($('#send_1').val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
    } else {
        alert('no comma');
    }
    return  false;
});
```

So how can I do this foreach `#send_X` when I do not know how many forms will exist and even don't want to write hundred times the same code just changing the `_x`?

If there is someone who could help I really would appreciate.

Comment: will wildcards work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697542/is-there-a-wildcard-class-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need loop solution see below code might be help

```
$(document).on("submit", "#paypal", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var i=1;
    $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {                   
        if ( /\,/.test( $('#send_'+i).val() ) ) {
            $('#send_'+i).val($('#send_'+i).val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
        } else {
            alert('no comma');
        }
        i++;
    });
    return  false;
});
```

or try changing

```
  $('#send_1').val()
```

with

```
  $( "input[id^='send']" ).val();
```

might work i am not sure

see [this](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) link

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for loop` like this (I've stripped out your `if` statement to simplify):

```js
$(document).on("submit", "#paypal", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var n = $("form").length; // get the number of forms

  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var form = $("#send_" + i); // gives you the form object        
  }
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3cjhft37/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add data-x-id for submit buttons and after get id from:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#paypal", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(e.target).attr('data-x-id');
    // for minimal work with dom
    var element = $('#send_'+id);
    var value = element.val();
    if ( /\,/.test( value ) ) {
        element.val(value.replace(/,/g, '.'));
    } else {
        alert('no comma');
    }
    return  false;
});
```