# jQuery search text in elements as SQL query LIKE?

Tags: javascript, search, jquery

Hi is there anyway to search text in dom, as we do for SQL query LIKE?

i mean, i have.

```
<ul>
<li>ab</li>
<li>abrecot</li>
<li>abus</li>
<li>aby</li>
<li>abrea</li>
</ul>
```

i would like to search for "abre" and so return in text ASC order:

```
<li>abrea</li>
<li>abrecot</li>
```

is this possible?

definitely the query would looks like doing:

```
SELECT <li> FROM <ul> WHERE text LIKE 'abre%' ORDER BY text ASC; :))
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but this may give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324798/how-to-search-an-array-in-jquery-like-sql-like-value-statement

Comment: uhm it search in array wich will be an array of elements, but he search for %text% i would like to search for text% :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are looking for elements whose text *starts with* a specified string, you can use the `filter` method:

```
var x = $("ul li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().substr(0, 4) === "abre";
});
```

This will only return elements which have the string "abre" at the start. The other answers using the `contains` method will return elements with the string found anywhere within them, which does not match your pseudo-SQL query.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/APzxv/3/) of the above.

Comment: Great answer. This answer is functionally equivalent to the SQL query you listed in your question.

Comment: wow, so if "abre" is somenthing user inputs, i need to put var q = $(input).val(); var x = $("ul li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().substr(0, q.length) === q;
});      right?

Comment: i really think i'm going to accept this as the answer :), thx man it was kind simple, but no one thought about that me too ))

Comment: just to be more specific, can you show me how can i return an array of cloned elements resulting from the filter? :P

Comment: `.filter(function() { ... }).clone();` will clone the matched set of elements.

Comment: hey man :P sorry again, can you take a look at this code cause i'm not able,once filtered and cloned, to print out the <a> elements, while with console.log i can see them when i put them into html it returns nothing printed :P

Comment: clones = $(".pajinate ul li a").filter(function() {return $(this).text().substr(0, q.length) === q;}).clone();if(q){
     var new_pajinate = '<ul class="pajinate"><li><ul>';
     $.each(clones,function(_i){
      new_pajinate +='<li>'+clones[_i]+'</li>';
          if(_i%5 == 1){
          new_pajinate+=
                      '</ul>'+
                      '</li>'+
                      '<li>'+
                      '<ul>';
                    }
                    new_pajinate += '</ul></li></ul>';
           console.log(clones[_i]);
     });
   $('.pajinate-content').html(new_pajinate);

Comment: @JamesAllardice Thanks, Your code was very helpful. See what i did with it http://jsfiddle.net/iolufemi/VaXhm/

Answer (score 5):

I think you would want the jQuery 'contains' function, have a look at the docs here:

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Your example would probably look like this:

```
$("li:contains('abre')")
```

EDIT to include the comments here, if you are looking for "starts with", you can do this on an element using the following syntax:

```
$('li[anAttribute^="abre"]')
```

But this assumes you have an attribute to query which i don't think you do, in which case the filters answer will likely suit your needs best.

Comment: wonderfull, i was also reading here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220851/element-or-class-like-selector-for-jquery

Comment: That will return elements containing the string anywhere, but the OP wants only elements starting with the string.

Comment: but what i'm afraid to, is that this searches %text% while i would like to search text% :P

Comment: I take your point and his psuedo query would indicate this, but when I read his text it said "search for "abre"" which i assumed to be a check for the existence of a string inside an element, rather than specifically starts with.

Answer (score 4):

The `:contains()` selector is probably what you're looking for:

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

QUOTE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>John Resig</div>

<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>


<script>
$("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will return elements containing the string anywhere, but the OP wants only elements starting with the string.

Comment: here the same, i'm afraid this will search for contained text not "starting with" text (text%)