# Like Statement jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I need to print some text if the result has similar text, is there a like statement in jquery? Similar to how you use LIKE in SQL?

```
if (r.events[i].room = 'craig')
                $('#'+r.events[i].slot).append('<br />').append('craighouse');
```

Comment: your if has one equal to symbol

Comment: @Tamizh this is probably the placeholder for the "like"

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569782/jquery-search-text-in-elements-as-sql-query-like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `LIKE` statement. However, you can search for one string within another using `indexOf()`:

```
if (r.events[i].room.indexOf('craig') != -1) // -1 = not found
    $('#'+r.events[i].slot).append('<br />').append('craighouse');
```

Comment: thanks for the response but I keep getting an error claiming "Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined "

Comment: `r.events[i].room` is undefined ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

It returns -1 if no match is found.

```
if (r.events[i].room.toUpperCase().indexOf('craig'.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                $('#'+r.events[i].slot).append('<br />').append('craighouse');
```

also, you can use [toUpperCase](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) if you don't want a match that depends on the case of the string.